# react native redux dispatch outside component is not trigger componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I have this dispatch outside of a react component myActions.js:

```js
import {SET_ORDER} from "./defaultActions";
import store from "../store";

const setOrder           = value => ({type: SET_ORDER,value});

export const addToOrder         = (item,type)=>{
    let order   = store.getState().order;//get object from store
    order[type].push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)));//clone new object to push on order array
    store.dispatch(setOrder(order));//dispatch new order object
};
```

In my Component i will receive props with:

```js
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {addToOrder} from "myActions.js";
class Drinks extends Component{
   componentDidMount(){
     this.someAction();//trigger update order
   }
   someAction(){
     addToOrder({something},'type');
   }

   componentWillReceiveProps(props){
     //not works
     //expect props.order but never appears
   }
}

const stateToProps      = ({order}) => ({order});
const dispatchToProps   = null; //not dispatch here


const conn = connect(stateToProps,dispatchToProps);

export default conn(Drinks);
```

The store it's updated, but componentWillReceiveProps is never called,how i need to do to receive props correctly?

My package redux libraries are: "react-redux": "^5.0.7","redux": "^3.7.2", "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0" my store is work fine between components, only fails when i try to dispatch outside a react component.

Comment: Are you sure your action is really dispatching? The code you've attached just creates the action object, but never calls `dispatch` on it (eg. `this.props.dispatch(addToOrder(....))` rather than just `addToOrder`)

Comment: Dispatch is in addOrder function inside myActions.js **store.dispatch(setOrder(order));//dispatch new order object**, my store is updated, if I print the properties after calling the function x I can see the updated state. but method componentWillReceiveProps is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really cloning the object (only the item), so you are updating the state in a mutable way which is why componentWillReceiveProps() is never called. Your order variable is still pointing to the order in the redux store. Try this:

```js
export const addToOrder = (item,type) => {
    let order   = {...store.getState().order}; //get cloned order object from store
    order[type].push(item); // push new object to cloned object
    store.dispatch(setOrder(order)); //dispatch new order object
};
```